# Angular default build option list for production environment

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Is there a place to view the default build options and its values for the `production` build for Angular CLI?

I see this part list the options for `development` build in the angular.json file:

```
"configurations": {
   "production": {
       "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
```

But it does not have the list of values for `production` build. Is the list of options listed somewhere in the docs?

Comment: You can add any variable in `enviroment.prod.ts` file and when you want build use `--prod` flag